# SQL state [null]; error code [0]; DSRA9110E: Connection is closed

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-connection, datasource

The below query runs fine in one environment but gives following error in another environment:

> SQL state [null]; error code [0]; DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.

Nested exception is

> com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.

I am unable to figure out 2 things:

1. What is meaning of this error SQL state [null]; error code [0]; DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.?
2. What is wrong with the environment where this query is failing?

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        PERS_ALST_NAVIG,
        PERS_ALST_PERSNUM,
    PERS_ALST_FIRSTNAME,
    PERS_ALST_LASTNAME, 
    PERS_ALST_DOB,
    ENT_PERS
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    TRIM(CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID) AS PERS_ALST_NAVIG,
    TRIM(CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID)  AS PERS_ALST_PERSNUM,
    FIRST_NAME              AS PERS_ALST_FIRSTNAME,
    LAST_NAME               AS PERS_ALST_LASTNAME, 
    DATE_OF_BIRTH           AS PERS_ALST_DOB
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    cust.CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID  ,
    cust.FIRST_NAME              ,
    cust.LAST_NAME               , 
    cust.DATE_OF_BIRTH               
    FROM V_CUSTOMERS cust 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN V_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_LINK cal
                 ON cust.CUSTOMER_SOURCE_UNIQUE_KEY1 = cal.CUSTOMER_SOURCE_UNIQUE_KEY1
                AND cust.customer_source_unique_key2 = cal.customer_source_unique_key2
    WHERE 
    cust.CUSTOMER_TYPE_GROUP = 'Person'
    and
    ([=reserved.function.call.OrgUnitFilterKeys('cust.ORG_UNIT_CODE', '/OrgUnit Filtering')])
    ) x 
    WHERE [whereCondition]
    ) y
```

Thanks in advance,
Reeya

Comment: you didnt open the connection

Comment: Or you opened it but it's closed for some reason; assuming you didn't close it then the database could have done perhaps, or a network/firewall timeout could have caused it to close, for example. Can only guess though.

Comment: How to open the connection?